# "Web Server" doesn't appear on the "connected devices" when configuring Flutter for web-development

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I want to setup Flutter to web-development and so I followed these instructions ([Link to Flutter web setup](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/web)):

```
$ flutter channel beta
$ flutter upgrade
$ flutter config --enable-web
$ flutter devices
```

The output should be the following:

```
2 connected device:

Web Server • web-server • web-javascript • Flutter Tools
Chrome     • chrome     • web-javascript • Google Chrome 81.0.4044.129
```

The problem is that my output doesn't contain the web-server:

```
2 connected devices:

Chrome (web) • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 88.0.4324.150
Edge (web)   • edge   • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 88.0.705.68
```

Can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `web-server` is not listed in `flutter devices` it's still available. We don't list it any more because it's always available, so there's no need to check for its existence. This is unlike a phone that needs to be connected via USB and configured to accept debug connections, or emulator/simulator that needs to be started outside the Flutter tool.